# Setup postscript printer in Windows 10 to print to cups 1.7.2 on linux system

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, printer, network-printer, cups

I am onto **64-bit** MS Windows 10 and want to print, **double-sided if possible**, to an older inkjet printer with no windows support attached to a linux Debian Jessie system.

In theory, it would be enough to install the generic MS Windows postscript driver (`MS Publisher Color Printer` for color or `MS Publisher Imagesetter` for b/w).

I can set up the printer via ipp print to 
`ipp://[name-of-printserver]:631/printers/[name-of-printer]` and print a test page alright.

Now, I want the MS Windows printer to have the features the cups ppd of this printer supplies (double-side, more trays) and install the **64-bit** driver automatically for MS Windows 10 on other 64-bit Windows 10 systems.

What is necessary to achieve this?